# JS Как перевести unicode в utf-8

Tags: javascript, кодировка, utf-8, unicode

У меня проблема, не знаю как преобразовать unicode в UTF-8.
У меня есть простенький код. Пытался сменить кодировку с помощью:

```
const utf8 = require('utf8');
utf8.encode(string)
```

Но не вышло. Вот сам код:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://pereveslo.pl.ua/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzlzHNxHA4jXosYdV",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"'
}
var form = {
    "action":"qmn_process_quiz",
    "complete_quiz":"confirmation",
    "currentuserTime":"1651600971",
    "currentuserTimeZone":"-",
    "mlwUserEmail":"-",
    "mlwUserName":"-",
    "qmn_question_list":"321Q",
    "qmn_quiz_id": "17",
    "qsm_hidden_questions": "",
    "timer": "215",
    "timer_ms": "2154500678991",
    "total_questions": "1"
}

request.post({ url: url, form: form }, function (e, r, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Вывод:

```
{"quizExpired":false,"display":"<div class=\"qsm-results-page\">\n\t\u0412\u0456\u0442\u0430\u0454\u043c\u043e,<strong> -!<br \/><\/strong>\u0412\u0438 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0439\u0448\u043b\u0438 \u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442 <strong>\u042f\u043a \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e? \u0427\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043d\u0430 1<br \/><\/strong>\u041f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u0445 \u0432\u0456\u0434\u043f\u043e\u0432\u0456\u0434\u0435\u0439:<strong><span class=\"template_name\">0<\/span>\u00a0<\/strong>\u0456\u0437<strong>1 (0%)!<br \/><br \/><div class='qsm_questions_answers_section'><div class='qmn_question_answer  qmn_question_answer_incorrect'><span class='mlw_qmn_question '><b><p>\u042f\u043a \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e?<br \/>\u0432\u0438\u043c\u041e\u0433\u0430 \/ \u0432\u0418\u043c\u043e\u0433\u0430<\/p><\/b>\r\n\u0412\u0430\u0448\u0430 \u0432\u0456\u0434\u043f\u043e\u0432\u0456\u0434\u044c: <span class=\"qmn_user_incorrect_answer\"> <\/span><br \/>\r\n\u041f\u0440\u0430\uu043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0440: NA<\/span><\/div><\/div><br \/><br \/><br \/><a href=\"https:\/\/pereveslo.pl.ua\">\u041f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0439\\/\/pereveslo.pl.ua\/quiz\/yak-pravylno\/\">\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0439\u0442\u0438 \u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442 \u0449\u0435 \u0440\u0430\u0437<\/a> <br \/><br \/>\u0412\u0438 \u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u0434\u0456\u043b\u0438\u0442\u0438\u0441\u044c \u0440\u0435\u0437\u0443\u043b\u044c\u0442\u0430\u0442\u0430\u043c\u0438 \u0443\u00a0 \u0424\u0435\u0439\u0441\u0431\u0443\u043a:<br \/><a class=\"mlw_qmn_quiz_link\" onclick=\"qmnSocialShare('facebook', 'I just scored 0% on \u042f\u043a \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e? \u0427\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043d\u0430 1!', '\u042f\u043a \u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e? \u0427\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043d\u0430 1', '594986844960937', 'https:\/\/pereveslo.pl.ua\/quiz\/yak-pravylno\/?result_id=12bd4cb023d90d27e4d6dd94a6d3ceea');\"><img src='https:\/\/pereveslo.pl.ua\/wp-content\/plugins\/quiz-master-next\/assets\/facebook.png' alt='Facebbok Share' \/><\/a><br \/><br \/><\/strong><\/div>\n","redirect":""}
```

Comment: Так вам же просто нужно раскодировать json да и всё, не? `console.log(JSON.parse(body))`